# Как вывести все записи пользователя на Django?

Tags: django

Скажу сразу, в Django начал разбираться только недавно.
Сделал регистрацию/вход для пользователей по инструкциям, работает, регистрирует, входит.

Хочу сейчас отобразить на главной странице (при входе пользователя), все записи которые были им созданы.

Но я не совсем понимаю как это сделать, от слова Совсем.

Буду очень признателен если кто-то поделится инструкцией вменяемой как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Допустим у нас следующая модель записи:

*models.py:*

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
```

Данная модель связаны с пользователем отношением `ForeignKey`, то есть у каждой записи может быть только 1 автор (пользователь), а у каждого пользователя может быть множество записей.

***Примеры:***

Чтобы получить все записи:

```py
Post.objects.all()
```

Чтобы получить все записи текущего пользователя:

```
Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)
```

Чтобы получить записи конкретного пользователя:

```py
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
Post.objects.filter(author=user)
```

***Вывод:***

Для того чтобы их вывести вам необходимо создать представление и шаблон.

Вот пример простого представления:

*views.py:*

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from my_app.models import Post


def post(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

*Примечание:

Для таких задач рекомендуется использовать представления на основе классов, подробнее можете прочитать в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/).*

Вот пример простого шаблона:

*index.html:*

```py
...
{% for post in posts %}
    <h3>{{ post.author }}</h3>
    <p>{{ post.text }}</p>
    <hr>
{% endfor %}
...
```

В данном шаблоне мы используем язык шаблонизатора Django. Это аналог цикла for в Python. Так как в шаблон поступает список постов, мы его итерируем, чтобы отобразить каждый пост.
Подробнее можете прочитать в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/language/).